# :class => "Insert Random Class Name Here"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is the point of doing something like this?

```
class User 
  has_many :students, :class_name => "CoachStudent", foreign_key: "coach_user_id"
 end 

class CoachStudent 
 belongs_to :student, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "student_user_id"
end
```

Why?

Why not User has many students, and Student belongs to User? That's the traditional way, yes?

**EDIT**

My befuddlement stems from the fact that there is no Student class per se. It's as listed in the code above. Hence this question.

ps. feel free to rename my post as I was at loss on how to title it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:class_name gives you the flexibility to name your associations whatever you want and make your code more readable and reusable. The :foreign_key attribute again allows you to decide what field you want as foreign key.

If you go with the usual convention:

```
class User
  has_many :students
end

class CoachStudent
  belongs_to :student
end
```

ActiveRecord by default, will use _id as the foreign key and try to find a class `Student` for the associations.  Clearly in your case, you want to use `:students` as your association name and map it to `CoachStudent`.  You get that flexibility by the :class_name convention.

Comment: that totally answered my question! thank you! just asking out of curiosity, why would someone want to do that? I know you said it can make code more readable and reusable, but you have to keep track of the changes you made mentally, and that seems more work.

Comment: A user is a very generic term and can be anything: a student, a coach, a teacher, a librarian, etc.  However, it makes more sense to classify these actors using your system as "users".  By going with your convention, I can add different fields pertaining to each class of user under one common table "User" and use :class_name, :foreign_key to define those different relationships.

Answer (score 3):

It gives a bit more meaning to the code.

I have no idea what a CoachStudent is in your example, but think of a blog example where a person is writing blog posts:

```
class BlogPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, class: 'User'
end
```

Yes you could technically say a post has a *user*, but it makes more sense (and has more meaning) if you say a post has an *author*.

Plus what if a post has multiple ties to users - for example, an author, a reviewer, and an approver? You need different names for the associations to distinguish them from each other.

Comment: cool name btw, I added an edit in my post above. My befuddlement stems from the fact that there is no Student class per se. So, CoachStudent is used in place of it, and all that modifier stuff.

Comment: you're saying that User can have multiple students in different roles, hence the CoachStudent thing above?

Comment: maybe they could - I don't know enough about your code to say. Your edit totally changes the question - I presume there would have been a reason that the CoachStudent was named differently, but likely no-one can say what it is, apart from the person who wrote it.

Comment: hm, does one have to know the code to understand why one did as posted in my post above? I see this pretty often, and didn't understand why someone would want to do this. When I first saw your answer, I knew you had answered it in a different context, hence my edit which was meant to clarify my post further. Apologies for any confusion.